# How to add days to current date in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using this:

```
var myDate = new Date(new Date().getTime()+(5*24*60*60*1000));
```

I get a date and time like this `2018-12-30T14:15:08.226Z`, but only i want is this `2018-12-30`. How can I retrieve just the date?

**This is Fixed. Thank You everyone who helps!!!

Comment: Can use angularjs date filter to return string in whatever format you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're experiencing a JS problem, it has nothing to do with Angular.

This will use `Date` methods to get all the data you want:

```
const date = new Date ();
let dateString = `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()}-${date.getDate()}`; 
// 2018-12-26
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the fact that the ISO 8601 format (what you are getting by implicitely converting to string) is well-codified with a separator `T`  between the date and time in order to split it.

`toISOString()` gives you what you're seeing. `split("T")` splits the string into an array of strings with `T` as separator. `[0]` then extracts the first element.

```js
var myDate = new Date(new Date().getTime()+(5*24*60*60*1000));
console.log(myDate.toISOString().split("T")[0]);
```